# Julia: Metaprogramming, evaluate string to string assignment?

Tags: string, julia, metaprogramming

Is it possible to evalute a string to an expression containing a string ?
To give a mwe :

```
eval(Meta.parse("x = 2"))
```

is evaluted to:

```
x = 2
```

But I would like x to be a string itself. My naive try in making x a string:

```
eval(Meta.parse("x = "2" "))
```

which i would like to be evaluted to

```
x = "2"
```

gives me an error. Therefore, my question is: Is it possible to do this, using only strings ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#Programming_and_data_formats) the quotation marks:

```
eval(Meta.parse("x = \"2\""))
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what i was searching for  :)

Answer (score 2):

@August has answered the question, however just one another way usually more practical when doing metaprogramming:

```
julia> eval(:(x= "2"));

julia> x
"2"
```

This nicely works with interpolation:

```
julia> z="hello";

julia> eval(:(x2 = $z));

julia> x2
"hello"
```